# How to get the 2nd table value repeated for number of rows from the first table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

attributes

```
id  value
1   asd
2   def
3   efg
4   jij
```

commision

```
id  comm
2   20
3   30
```

I want the result as

```
value,  comm
asd     20
def     30
efg     20
jij     30
```

The 2nd table value repeat as per the 1st table records.

Comment: Huh?  It looks like the ids should be related, given that they have the same name.   Please explain more clearly.

Comment: @selva `The 2nd table value repeat as per the 1st table records.` how??

Comment: it doesn't matter with the ids, for every record in the first table, i want to get value from 2nd table either random or sequential.

Comment: i mean, if 1st table has 50 records and 2nd table has only 5 records, i want 50 records filled with repeat of the 5 records from 2nd table.

Comment: But why do you want to "pair" unrelated values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to repeat, use `row_number()` and arithmetic:

```
select c.*, a.*
from (select a.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum, count(*) over () as cnt
      from attributes a
     ) a join
     (select c.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from commission c
     ) c
     on a.seqnum - 1 = mod(c.seqnum, a.cnt);
```